# Data lookup based on measure

Tags: dynamic, powerbi, dax, ranking

I am looking for some help in creating a measure to figure out data based on a ranking measure.

I have attached my Power BI file showing my issues and formulae.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/s7xted6lhh38dpo/Test.pbix?dl=0

Essentially, I have few tables that have been mapped. Showing revenue achieved by each employee for each product. The employees are split into 3 Teams.

I want to be able to rank these teams based on various filters that can be selected from one of the visualisations. – I have created the measure to do this using the below formulae:
Rev Measure = SUM(Sales[Rev])
Team Rank = RANKX(ALLSELECTED(Org[Team]),CALCULATE([Rev Measure]))

Now I want to create 2 card visualisation that dynamically fills in the data based on the ranking. So one card would read:

Commentary 1 = "Overall Sales was at $"& [Rev Measure] &". With the best performing Team being Team C bringing in $1220 of Revenue"

In the above commentary I am able to dynamically input the total revenue. However, I am unsure how to proceed with showing the best performing team data.

In the second card visualisation I want to show the worst performing team.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Look into TOPN to get equivalent of RANK but as a filter.

Comment: Thanks, but that wont help with the commentary above as I'm looking to have all up data and ranked data.